# Concat list of tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 2 columns `DBName`, `TableName`.

| DbName | tablename |
| --- | --- |
| A | mail |
| B | mail |
| c | mail |
| D | mail |

How can I concatenate the content of all the tables listed in that table in SQL Server?

Not all the tables have the same structure. The columns I need to retrieve are id, sent, date.

I am using the code shown here, but when I run it, I get an error:

> Msg 207 Invalid column name

but the column exists in all the tables

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'SELECT id, sent, date FROM' + QUOTENAME(DBName) + '.[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(TableName) + ' UNION ALL'
FROM #TableNames

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @result OUTPUT

SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES (@result)) AS RESULT(result)
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing a blank space after FROM and before ', so it should be *FROM '* and not *FROM'*

Comment: FYI, using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Comment: `PRINT @sql` is an easy way to troubleshoot dynamic SQL.

Comment: If you `PRINT` your SQL, as well, you'll see it contains syntax errors; I wouldn't expect to get the error you get, I'd expect you to get the error *"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21 Incorrect syntax near 'ALLSelect'."*

Comment: `, @result OUTPUT` will not assign the result set to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches.   Consider the first one using `string_agg()`

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([DbName] varchar(50),[tablename] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('A','mail')
,('B','mail')
,('c','mail')
,('D','mail')

-- First Method 
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
Select @SQL = string_agg('SELECT id, sent, date FROM '+quotename(DBName)+'.[dbo].'+quotename(tablename),' Union All ') from @YourTable


-- Second/Dated Method
Declare @SQL varchar(max)=''

Select @SQL = @SQL + ' Union All SELECT id, sent, date FROM '+ quotename(DBName)+'.[dbo].'+quotename(tablename)
 From  @YourTable

Select @SQL = stuff(@SQL,1,11,'')
```

Both Return

```
SELECT id, sent, date FROM [A].[dbo].[mail] Union All 
SELECT id, sent, date FROM [B].[dbo].[mail] Union All 
SELECT id, sent, date FROM [c].[dbo].[mail] Union All 
SELECT id, sent, date FROM [D].[dbo].[mail]
```

Comment: I still **strongly** recommend not using the [documented antipattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment). As the OP is on 2012, they won't have access to `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: @ThomA I'm with you, but honestly, over the years, I've never experienced an issue.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, the problem with this technique is that it's execution plan dependent and an accident waiting to happen (most commonly occurs with `ORDER BY`). "just because it works, doesn't mean it's right".

Comment: I admit, I've only seen it happen at most a handful of times, but it *has* happened.

Comment: From my experience, it doesn't start to happen until an ORDER BY is involved

Answer (score 0):

To your original question, it is failing because you have no space at the end of your line before you concantenate the next line. So it's spitting out `...union allSELECT id`.

As for your technique, as mentioned by others, you should not be using the documented antipattern of successively updating a string. And unfortunately since you are not running a newer version of SQL, you don't have access to the wonderfunction `string_agg`. So here is an approach which should work for 2012 and earlier.

It involves using `FOR XML` to generate a concatenated string. the `type` argument ensures that the entire expression is output as xml, which is important if there are characters that would have to be HTML encoded (such as left or right arrows). the `.value(N'.', 'nvarchar(max)')` just turns that into the string you're after, while guaranteeing you retain all the characters exactly as you want.

Wrap the whole thing in a `stuff` statement to cut off the leading text you want on all rows *except* the first, and you should be all set.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

drop table if exists #YourTable
create table #YourTable
(
    DbName varchar(50),
    tablename varchar(50)
)
insert into #YourTable
values 
    ('A', 'mail'),
    ('B', 'mail'),
    ('c', 'mail'),
    ('D', 'mail')

select @SQL = 
stuff
(

    (
        select ' Union All SELECT id, sent, date FROM '+ quotename(DBName)+'.[dbo].'+quotename(tablename)
        from #YourTable
        for xml path(''),type
    ).value(N'.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    1,
    11,
    ''
)
```

I can't find a great canonical reference to this technique on stack overflow, and in particular the use of `type`, but this is how I'd do it if you don't have `string_agg`.